# Regular Expression to match two strings in AND condition

Tags: regex, string, match

I am new to regular expression, please kindly help me on the error scenario where I need to use regex to match two error messages (appearing in different lines, but same paragraph) in AND condition from a log file:

`Msg1 - ERROR [com.company.util.ejb.TimedBean] () FAILED processing Loader`

`Msg2 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Message code:[SL] is unknown.`

Basically, what I need is to match `(msg1)&&(msg2)`, in this case, (ERROR...Loader) will appear in the first line and (java...unknown) will follow in the next line. The messages will always follow this order. I am not programming in any typical language here, they will be put into a enterprise tool that accepts regexp.

If possible, would you also show me how to make it in Or condition as `(msg1)||(msg2)`?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve ... Can you explain betteR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching two consecutive lines is, in theory, just a matter of putting the two regular expressions end-to-end.  So for purposes of illustration, let's say you've got a file named `logfile.txt` that contains messages you're looking for.  Then from a Linux command line you could do something like this:

```
pcregrep -M -o '^ERROR\N*Loader$\njava\N*unknown\.$\n' logfile.txt
```

and it would print the line pairs that you're looking for.  Breaking it down into parts:

- `^ERROR` matches the word ERROR at the beginning of a line.
- `\N*` matches any number of characters that aren't a line terminator.
- `Loader$` matches the word Loader at the end of a line.
- `\n` matches the newline character.  (Might be different on Windows.)
- `java\N*unknown\.$\n` is more of the same.

BUT... And this is a big problem... The tool that handles your regular expression must be capable of doing multi-line matches, and that capability must be turned on.  (That's what the `-M` command line option to `pcregrep` enables.)  Many regexp tools, such as plain `grep` on many systems, can't do multiline searches.  So you may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks csd. I don't know why but "\N" doesn't work in my tool (maybe I didn't put it in the right way). I was able to enable the multi-line match feature. The final regexp I used was `/(ERROR.*\n).+(java\.lang\.RuntimeException\: Message code\:\[SL\] is unknown.*\n)/i` - it doesn't look as efficient as yours, but works for me!

Comment: Hmm... Here is a better one: `/ERROR.+java\.lang\.RuntimeException\: Message code\:\[SL\] is unknown/s`

Comment: If `\N` isn't supported, you could write it as `[^\n]` (i.e. the class of characters that isn't `\n`).  The reason you might want to do it that way (instead of just using `.+`) is that you don't want your regular expression to match from the top of your file down to the last match at the bottom.